# IOS TDD: UITableViewCell selection segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tdd, segue

Hi I actually develop an app using TDD. The App uses Storyboards. I have an UITableViewController performing a segue after cell selection. The code works but my Test for the segue always fails.

Is there something special with Segue and TDD? Using the traditional didSelectRowAtIndexPath workflow works. But I want to use storyboards with all benefits.

Here is my TestCode:

```
    - (void)testThatAfterPerformingSegueForSecondRowTheSessionHasSescondQuestSelected
{
    NSIndexPath *secondQuestPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *secondCell = [sut tableView:sut.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:secondQuestPath];

    [sut performSegueWithIdentifier:kStationsSegueIdentifier sender:secondCell];

    MNVQuest *quest = session.quests[1];

    assertThat(session.selectedQuest, is(quest));
}
```

Here is my Code for the ViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kStationsSegueIdentifier]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSLog(@"ROW: %d", selectedIndexPath.row);
        _session.selectedQuest = _session.quests[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the identifier is set in storyboard?

Comment: it's set and I have also a test for this

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code snippets if your test's `session` is the same as you tableViewController's instanceVariable `_session` that get's modified in `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Maybe your test has to check for something like:

```
assertThat(sut.session.selectedQuest, is(quest));
```